# How to get a set in this way in TLA+?

Tags: tla+

Hello I'm a newbie in TLA+.

I knew that Cartesian product is something like this:
 S × T × U = {<<a, b, c>> : a ∈ S, b ∈ T,c ∈ U }.

The result of product is a set of sequence.

And I wonder how can I get a set like this in TLA+,if I have sets S,T and U:
{{a, b, c} : a ∈ S, b ∈ T,c ∈ U }.

This set's element should be sets,not sequences.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to summarize the excellent answer on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/tlaplus/c/lnFkUsD4rTs): insert a colon into the mathematical definition and use `\in`, then you're there:

```
A == {1,2,3}
B == {"a","b","c"}
C == {42,23}
Tuples == { <<a,b,c>> : a \in A, b \in B, c \in C} 
Sets == { {a,b,c} : a \in A, b \in B, c \in C}
```

Creating a model and choosing "evaluate constant expression" you can enter `Tuples` to get:

```
{ <<1, "a", 23>>,
     <<1, "a", 42>>,
     <<1, "b", 23>>,
     <<1, "b", 42>>,
     <<1, "c", 23>>,
     <<1, "c", 42>>,
     <<2, "a", 23>>,
     <<2, "a", 42>>,
     <<2, "b", 23>>,
     <<2, "b", 42>>,
     <<2, "c", 23>>,
     <<2, "c", 42>>,
     <<3, "a", 23>>,
     <<3, "a", 42>>,
     <<3, "b", 23>>,
     <<3, "b", 42>>,
     <<3, "c", 23>>,
     <<3, "c", 42>> }
```

If you try the same with `Sets` it won't work because TLC can only evaluate homogenous sets but we would need to mix integers and strings here (this is a design decision of TLC, the language itself allows us to express this).  Setting `B == {100}` we get:

```
{ {1, 23, 100},
     {1, 42, 100},
     {2, 23, 100},
     {2, 42, 100},
     {3, 23, 100},
     {3, 42, 100} }
```

I can also highly recommend Leslie Lamport's book [Specifying Systems](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/tla/book.html). It explains TLA+ in detail and has a chapter on TLC as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question but I'd think this would work

```
---- MODULE stack_overflow_question ----

S == {"a"}
T == {"b"}
U == {"c"}
alltogether == S \union T \union U

====
```

At least this is what I get back when I evaluate "alltogether"

```
Evaluating constant expression:
alltogether

{"a", "b", "c"}
```

Comment: Are you sure he is not looking for all combinations/permutations? The cross product of 3 sets S,T,U would be be a set of all possible combinations, not? S = {0,1}, T = {2,3}, U = {4,5} => whatever = `((0 (2 4 5) (3 4 5)) (1 (2 4 5) (3 4 5)))`

Comment: Nope--not sure about that at all, hence my verbiage "Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question" :)